# How can I a React microfrontend get access to react and other npm-installed packages from NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, webpack-module-federation

I have a vanilla NextJS setup where I dynamically load microfrontends from my CDN. The microfrontends are developed using React with a custom webpack setup. Within the webpack setup, I have "react", "react-dom" and other shared libraries listed within "externals". When I load the microfrontend, "react" and the other shared libraries come back as undefined--it seems that NextJS doesn't expose these npm-installed packages and libraries. Is there a way to get access to those and have it work with "externals" from the microfrontend? So far, I've tried dynamically importing and exposing those packages but I suspect that's an anti-pattern. Any other non-hacky way of doing this? I'm also trying to avoid the private (non-free) Module Federation offered for NextJS users.

Comment: Why are they listed as `external`? I mean if you need code from these libraries, you have two options: 1. Make them available in the browser by importing them separately or 2. Bundle them with the microfrontend. What's the strategy? :) If same libraries are used by multiple microfrontends, I'd go with 1, otherwise 2.

Comment: React and react-dom are both undefined when I search for it within the window object. How can I expose that? I can’t find any documentation for it anywhere on NextJS.

Comment: They come as undefined because you have told your bundler that they will be available through other means in your production environment. You can read here about how to import React right into the browser: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html